# Loading Specific Content from another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
index.html 
<script >
function loadPage(){
    var xhttp,rtext,x;
    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
           rtext=xhttp.responseText;
            x = rtext.getElementById('bottom');
        }
        document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML=x;
    };
    xhttp.open("GET","first.html",true);
    xhttp.send();
}

 </script>
    <body>
    <div onClick="loadPage();">Home</div>
    <div id="firstdiv"></div>
    </body>  

first.html

    <body>
    <div id="bottom">
    <p>content 1</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="bottom1">
    content 2
    </div>
    </body>
```

i need to load only  "bottom" div from first.html  to my index page using javascript only and facing error.

getElementById('bottom')  is not define property .

How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [creating a new document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument) with the contents of 'first.html', then query that document for the element you want.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Doc Title");
doc.body.outerHTML = rtext;
var bottom = doc.getElementById('bottom');
```

Not tested, but that could be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

---

JavaScript operates only on the elements of the current page.  When the code executes

```
rtext=xhttp.responseText;
x = rtext.getElementById('bottom');
```

It is expecting to locate 'bottom' on index.html.  When the response is loaded into x, x contains the text of first.html but it is not recognized as html, and cannot be interpreted as such.

I agree with the answer from e-e - it's a starting place.